# Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I would like to solve in Python the following Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming in Python. Nevertheless, I'm not familiar with the optimization 
toolboxes of Python.

Can someone provide an example of code with the vectors X1, X2, X3, X4 given as below ?

```
X1 = np.array([3,10,20,10])
X2 = np.array([5,1,3,4])
X3 = np.array([2,3,1,4])
X4 = np.array([10,0,1,2])
```

The MIQP is written as :
[image]

I tried to solve it with CVXPY but i encoutered problem with the boolean 
variable `x = cp.Variable(1, boolean=True)`:

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

X1 = np.array([3,10,20,10])
X2 = np.array([5,1,3,4])
X3 = np.array([2,3,1,4])
X4 = np.array([10,0,1,2])

M = 100

x = cp.Variable(1, boolean=True)
Y1 = cp.Parameter(4)
Y2 = cp.Parameter(4)
a = cp.Parameter(1)
b = cp.Parameter(1)
c = cp.Parameter(1)
d = cp.Parameter(1)
delta = cp.Variable(1)

constraints = [Y1 <= X1 - a, 
           Y1 <= X2 - b, 
           Y1 >= X1 - a - M*delta,
           Y1 >= X2 - b - M*(1-delta),
           Y2 <= X3 - c, 
           Y2 <= X4 - d, 
           Y2 >= X3 - c - M*delta,
           Y2 >= X4 - d - M*(1-delta),
           0 <= a, a <= 10,
           0 <= b, b <= 5,
           0 <= c, c <= 5,
           0 <= d, d <= 10,
           delta == x]

obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(Y1-Y2))
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
print(prob.solve())
```

Comment: Did you try [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/)?

Comment: I didnt how for CVXPY, so i tried to code this problem with CVXPY and i updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cvxpy`, parameter is something you have a value to set to it. In your problem, basically all symbols other than the `X1` to `X4` are *variables*. So do a global replace of `cp.Parameter` to `cp.Variable` will work.

Then, I found the result to be

```
$ python3 cvxtest.py
69.99998471073722
```

Comment: Thank you for your ansmer ! But i still have the following error message x = cp.Variable(1, boolean=True), TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'boolean' and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @user41037 Your are probably using an old version. Compare [new API](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#mixed-integer-programs) with [old API](https://www.cvxpy.org/versions/0.4.11/tutorial/advanced/index.html#mixed-integer-programs). ECOS cannot solve that, ECOS_BB might do it; but it's not a real MIQP-solver and without the commercials you will have problems to get one usable from cvxpy (see [this table](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver)).

Comment: Than you for your answer ! it works ! But my goal was to find the variables a,b,c,d that minimize the objective function. How one can handle it with cvxpy ? thank you.

Comment: `print(Y1.value)`, for example.

Comment: Do yo know how to replace the variable delta, with four binary variables delta1,delta2,delta3,delta4 and add the constraint delta1+delta2+delta3+delta4 = 1 ? thank you.

Comment: `delta = cp.Variable(4)` and `cp.sum(delta) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

[Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the APOPT solver can handle MIQP problems in addition to more general Nonlinear Mixed Integer Programming (MINLP). The solution is:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   2.610000000277068E-002 sec
 Objective      :    70.0000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
x:  1.0
obj:  70.0
```

Here is the Python script:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
X1 = m.Param([3,10,20,10])
X2 = m.Param([5,1,3,4])
X3 = m.Param([2,3,1,4])
X4 = m.Param([10,0,1,2])
M = 100
p = m.Array(m.FV,4,lb=0,ub=10); a,b,c,d=p
b.upper = 5; c.upper = 5
for pi in p:
    pi.STATUS=1
x = m.FV(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True); x.STATUS=1
Y1,Y2 = m.Array(m.Var,2)
delta = m.FV(); delta.STATUS=1

m.Equations([Y1 <= X1 - a, 
             Y1 <= X2 - b, 
             Y1 >= X1 - a - M*delta,
             Y1 >= X2 - b - M*(1-delta),
             Y2 <= X3 - c, 
             Y2 <= X4 - d, 
             Y2 >= X3 - c - M*delta,
             Y2 >= X4 - d - M*(1-delta),
             delta == x])

m.Minimize((Y1-Y2)**2)
m.options.IMODE=2
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
print('x: ', x.value[0])
print('obj: ', m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```